# Not able able configure turnoff Duplex on remote machine using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell-3.0

```
Not able to turnoff duplex printing using printer preferences
```

## By Default Print Queue will be set to duplex two sided long edge value and i want to turn off that so Simplex Index will be 1 for that.

```
[int]$SimplexIndex = 1
```

## Function to disable duplex

```
Function Disable-Duplex()
{
Param ([int]$DuplexIndex)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Printing
Add-Type -AssemblyName ReachFramework
$permissions = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministrateServer
$printServer = New-Object System.Printing.LocalPrintServer
$validation = New-Object System.Printing.ValidationResult
$deltaTicket = New-Object System.Printing.PrintTicket 
$DefaultPrintQueue = $printServer.DefaultPrintQueue
$PrintQueueName =$DefaultPrintQueue.FullName
$deltaTicket.Duplexing =$DuplexIndex
$validation = $DefaultPrintQueue.MergeAndValidatePrintTicket($DefaultPrintQueue.UserPrintTicket, $deltaTicket)

if($validation.ValidatedPrintTicket.Duplexing -eq $deltaTicket.Duplexing)
{
   $DefaultPrintQueue.UserPrintTicket = $validation.ValidatedPrintTicket
   $DefaultPrintQueue.Commit()
   Write-Host ("PrintTicket new duplexing setting is set on $PrintQueueName")
}
else
{
  Write-Host ("PrintTicket new duplexing setting is constrained on $PrintQueueName")
}

[string]$RemoteVMIPAdress = "XXXXXX" # Mandatory Input Variable
[string]$User = "XXXXXXXXX" # Mandatory Input Variable
[string] $UserName = "$RemoteVMIPAdress\$User"
[string] $PassWord = "test@123" # Mandatory Input Variable

#Enabling WinRM (Windows Remote Management)
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force

#Encrypting the Password
[SecureString]$secureString = $PassWord | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
[PSCredential]$credentialsObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$secureString

#Creating new PS Session
$sess = New-PSSession -Credential $credentialsObject -ComputerName $RemoteVMIPAdress
```

## Executing the Function on remote computer

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock ${Function:Disable-Duplex} -ArgumentList $SimplexIndex
```

Comment: If i run the above code i am getting following error, Exception calling "Commit" with "0" argument(s): "An exception occurred while committing the properties for 
the PrintQueue object. Win32 error: The request is not supported.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PrintCommitAttributesException
    + PSComputerName        : XXXXXX

Comment: If i run same code on remote machine locally, it is working fine. The problem with the remote execution only.